# Why folder like structure not working for Zeppelin?

Tags: apache, user-interface, github, apache-zeppelin

I am referring to the issue:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-209
- https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/796#issuecomment-201122281

In my zeppelin note names separated by "forward-slash" (/) do not result in Folder type structure.[image]

An ideal case should be the one I have provided in the link above. C should be inside B folder, while B should be inside A folder. However, as of now A/B/C is a single note. It seems to be working for everyone but not for me. I have also pulled latest changes from GitHub repository of Apache Zeppelin.

I appreciate any sort of help from SO community. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Sumit Sidana

You need to change this page.

[image]